# Replace a class within the Java class library with a custom version

Tags: java, patch, swingx

The class *BasicLabelUI* in *javax/swing/plaf/basic* is affected by a [confirmed bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7172652).
In my application I *need* functionality provided by the [fixed version (filed for v9)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/f4fb05e323a0/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.java).
Due to both legal and technical reasons, I'm still bound to the affected JDK version.

My approach was to create a package *javax/swing/plaf/basic* inside my project, containing the fixed version.

How can I force my project to favor my included version of the class over the defective class in the installed JDK?

This has to be somewhat portable as the fixed class also has to be working on customer side and the defective class in the JDK installation has to be disregarded. Therefore, I dont want to modify the JDK, but rather bypass this particular class.

Comment: Strangely, I am unable to reproduce this bug in Java 1.7.0_75 or 1.8.0_65, in Windows 7, using the code from the bug submission.  I tried modifying it to use the default look-and-feel;  I tried adding use of EventQueue.invokeLater to the main method.  (I was hoping to experiment with an InputMap-based workaround.)

Comment: I can reproduce the erroneous behaviour using the code from http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7172652. I'm using 1.8.0_45

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned by the other answers, you **could** in theory of course unzip your JVM's *rt.jar* file and replace the file with a compatible bugfixed version.

Any classes of the Java Class library such as those of Swing are loaded by the *bootstrap class loader* which looks up its classes from this *rt.jar*. You can generally not **prepend** classes to this classpath without adding them to this file. There is a (non-standard) VM option

```
-Xbootclasspath/jarWithPatchedClass.jar:path
```

where you would prepend a jar file that includes the patched version, but this does not necessarily work on any Java virtual machine. Also, it is **illegal to deploy an application** that changes this hehavior! As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> Do not deploy applications that use this option to override a class in
>   rt.jar because this violates the Java Runtime Environment binary code
>   license.

If you however appended a class to the bootstrap class loader (what is possible without using non-standard APIs by using the instrumentation API), the runtime would still load the original class as the bootstrap class loader in this case searches the *rt.jar* first. It is therefore impossible to "shadow" the broken class without modifying this file.

Finally, it is always [illegal to distribute a VM with a patched file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/oedq/help/1541484.txt), i.e. putting it into a production system for a customer. The license agreement states clearly that you need to

> [...] distribute the [Java runtime] complete and unmodified and only bundled as part of your applets and applications

Changing the VM that you distribute is therefore not recommended as you might face legal consequences when this is ever uncovered.

Of course, you can in theory build your own version of the OpenJDK but you could not call the binary *Java* anymore when you distribute it and I assume that your customer would not allow for this by what you suggest in your answer. By experience, many secure environments compute hashes of binaries before execution what would prohibit both approaches of tweaking the executing VM.

The easiest solution for you would probably be the creation of a [Java agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that you you add to your VM process on startup. In the end, this is very similar to adding a library as a class path dependency:

```
java -javaagent:bugFixAgent.jar -jar myApp.jar
```

A Java agent is capable of replacing a class's binary representation when the application is started and can therefore change the implementation of the buggy method.

In your case, an agent would look something like the following where you need to include the patched class file as a ressource:

```
public static class BugFixAgent {
  public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
    inst.addClassFileTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
      @Override
      public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, 
                              String className, 
                              Class<?> classBeingRedefined, 
                              ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, 
                              byte[] classfileBuffer) {
        if (className.equals("javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI")) {
          return patchedClassFile; // as found in the repository
          // Consider removing the transformer for future class loading
        } else {
          return null; // skips instrumentation for other classes
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The javadoc `java.lang.instrumentation` package offers a detail description of how to build and implement a Java agent. Using this approach, you can use the fixed version of the class in question **without breaking the license agreement**.

From experience, Java agents are a great way for fixing temporary bugs in third party libraries and in the Java Class Library without needing to deploy changes in your code or even being required to deploy a new version for a customer. As a matter of fact, this is a typical use case for using a Java agent.

Comment: If you are going to modify the JVM behavior, there is a simpler way.  But I think this is breaking the (I guess) customer's rules.

Comment: I do not think that a customer has a problem when instrumenting the classes of a process that runs a Swing application (i.e. most likely a dedicated VM). In the end, most customers want a bug-free version. What you suggest is however a legal breach of the Java license agreement.

Comment: You didn't read my Answer fully.  See 1st paragraph after the line.

Comment: I suggested THREE things.  And recommend one of them ... which is definitely not not illegal.  Besides, my suggestion #1 is only a violation of the Oracle binary license if the Oracle binary license applies.  It does not if you build from the OpenJDK sources (GPLv2) and follow the GPL rules.  Read these ... http://openjdk.java.net/legal/

Comment: The OP stated that migrating VM version is not an option what excludes your suggestions of either building your own VM or tweaking an existing VM (disregarding the fact that you are not legally allowed to alter binaries). If you meant the `-X` option that I also suggested, you should be more specific with your answer. Nothing of what the OP stated suggests that using a Java agent would be inapplicable for the use case. Finally, your first sentence says that what the OP wants is not possible what is neither true and contradicted by your own answer, thus my disagreement.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter So does  this BugFixAgent  overrule the ill-conditioned class in the JDK?

Comment: @bogus Yes, both approaches will work. The agent works on any standard VM, the "prepend to class path" solution only works on current versions of HotSpot.

Comment: The prepend to classpath approach ALSO works on older versions of Hotspot, and will probably continue to work in future versions .... unless you have evidence that they are going to withdraw this feature.

Comment: Also, -Xbootstrapclasspath is available on (at least) the IBM and Oracle JRockit java command.  It is not exclusive to Hotspot as you imply.

Comment: I imply that X-prefixed options are not supported. sun.misc.Unsafe exists on all platforms, yet it goes away.