# Override a Java class from another project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I´m something new in Java Development and I will try to ask my question short and simple. Hope it works :-).

### The Goal

Extend some Java classes from a given project without editing the original source files.

### The Problem

It don´t work ;-)

### Short description

I have two Java projects. **Project A** is a bigger *Web project*. **Project B** is a *Web Fragment project*. I want to extend some classes from **Project A**, but I don´t want edit the original sources. So the idea is to extend the classes in **Project B**.

### Current state

#### Create Project B

I created Project B with the Eclipse Wizard

```
File > New > Project > Web Fragment Project
```

and add **Project B** to the *Dynamic Web project*, **Project A**

#### Add class to Project B

Now I copied the original Java class into **Project B** using the same folder structure as in **Project A**

```
Project A > WebContent > WEB-INF > src > a > b > c > MyClass.java
Project B > WebContent > WEB-INF > src > a > b > c > MyClass.java
```

And both classes are in the same package

```
package a.b.c;
```

So far so good. I write some test output for the console to check if the class will be overridden correctly.

### Deployment

I deploy **Project A** and start the Tomcat Server. But my test output is not logged to the console. So I suspect, **MyClass.java** will be not overridden. Why?

### Additional informations

#### Project A properties

- **Project B** is in *Web Deployment Assembly* from **Project A**
- I added **Project B** in the *Projects Tab* of the *Java Build Path*
- Under the *Order and Export Tab* i move **Project B** over **Project A**

### Question(s)

Why will the original class in **Project A**not be overridden from *MyClass.java* in **Project B**. Have i something overseen?

Thank you in advance and best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Can you please share the code snippets and any error trace ( if you see )

Comment: by overriding do you mean extending I guess....

Comment: As your intention is to make project B's class the preferred one, why don't you set project B above project A's sources in the deployment assembly?

Comment: Put project A into a versioning system, create a branch for the modifications you want to do the class (BTW class names ALWAYS begin with uppercase) and avoid this kind of ugly, unmaintainable contraptions.

Comment: I correct the order in the deployment assemby, in Eclipse it is correct, just wrote it down false.

Comment: Correct the class name. Now it begins uppercase :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the JVM to use the patched class. In order to do that you match the package and class name for the patching class. The magic happens in the `classpath`. The JVM loads the class search in sequence. This means you set your patch to be first loaded e.g.

`set CLASSPATH=..\yourPatch;..\theJar.jar`

The Eclipse IDE has this as a built in function. You can find it

```
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Class Folder
```

Add your patched class as the first entry.

Comment: @That's how I use it and it works. Maybe you did something wrong in the steps before. See here for more reading material https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631419/replace-a-class-within-the-java-class-library-with-a-custom-version

Comment: Thank you. I will try it further.